# Pythonic way to loop over all pairs of a list

Tags: python

I was really surprised that I couldn't find this anywhere. 
In most languages, going through all possible pairs in a list looks something like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < length; i++) 
    for (j = i + 1; j < length; j++)
         do stuff
```

But in python, you would have to do:

```
for i in range (len(clusters)):
    for j in range (i+1, len(clusters)):
        do stuff
```

I feel like that isn't very pythonic. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: I'd do it this way: `[(i,j) for i in xrange(1,len(mylist)) for j in xrange(i,len(mylist))]` You could also call some function `foo(i,j)` of course.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [combinations()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
from itertools import combinations
combinations('ABCD', 2) --> AB AC AD BC BD CD
```

Python discourages "C-style" loops, because you actually hardly need them if you adapt to it. You can do it quite easily using `emumerate()` to still get the index, and some slicing, using pure python:

```
lst = 'ABCD'
for index, first in enumerate(lst):
    for second in lst[index+1:]:
        print(first, second)
```